# What is the correct sentence: “Who are we?” or “Who we are?”

Tags: grammaticality, difference, questions, word-order, inversion

I searched the Internet to find which of the following is correct:

> - Who are we?
> - Who we are?

And I found that both are used. What is the correct sentence?

Comment: Can you share your research with us? As a stand-alone phrase, "Who we are?" is not correct. It can be used as part of a longer sentence, however: "Who we are is irrelevant." So I'm not sure where you saw that both are correct.

Comment: @WendiKidd "Who we are?" can be correct; for example, if somebody says "I don't know anymore who we are." the reply could be "Who we are? We are a couple who pretend everything is fine."

Answer (score 7):

"Who are we?" is correct.

The general forms of a question in English are:

> Single verb: interrogative pronoun (who, what, where, when, why how -- verb -- subject
>
> Two verbs: interrogative pronoun -- helping verb (usually forms of "to be" or "to do") -- subject -- primary verb -- object

Single verb examples:

> When is the next train?
>
> Where are the books?

Two verbs:

> Why do you think that?
>
> How did Bob find the house?

Note this is different from the standard word order for a declarative sentence, which is: subject -- verb -- object.

> Declarative: The book is here.
>
> Interrogative: Where is the book?
>
> Declarative: She is running.
>
> Interrogative: What is she doing?

Etc.

Answer (score -1):

Who are we? is a question.

"Who we are" is not a question but an introduction to the information that follows. I conclude that it should be followed by a colon. Who we are:

Answer (score -3):

Who we are can be correct for example when a person/company wants to introduce the values they stand for.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Paolo, and thank you for your answer. While "Who we are" can be used in the way that you suggest, it would not be followed by a question mark when used in that way. Typically, it would only be used as a heading in a document, and would not have any punctuation.

Comment: @JavaLatte, the exception to that rule:  If someone wrote "Who we are" and you were questioning that usage, you might ask, "Who we are?"